# Как правильно использовать WHERE NOT EXISTS в моем случае?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две сущности:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TaskData] (
  [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, 
  [Code] INT NOT NULL, 
  [Power] INT NOT NULL, 
  [Process] FLOAT (53) NOT NULL, 
  [Order] FLOAT (53) NOT NULL, 
  [Name] FLOAT (53) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QueryData] (
  [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, 
  [Code] INT NOT NULL, 
  [TerritoryCode] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
  [TaskCode] INT NOT NULL, 
  [TargetCostItems] INT NOT NULL, 
  [ProcessingSign] INT NOT NULL, 
  [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

В `dbo.TaskData` есть много дубликатов с одним и тем же `Code`. Вот так от них избавляюсь и объединяю в одну таблицу:

```
  INSERT INTO dbo.DataFull (
      CodeQuery, TerritoryCode, TaskCode, 
      TargetCostItems, ProcessingSign, 
      Name, CodeTask, Power, Process, Order
      ) 
  SELECT 
      query.Code AS CodeQuery, 
      query.TerritoryCode, 
      query.TaskCode, 
      query.TargetCostItems, 
      query.ProcessingSign, 
      query.Name, 
      task.CodeTask as TaskCode, 
      task.Power, 
      task.Proces, 
      task.Order 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      task.Code AS CodeTask, 
      max(task.Power) AS Power, 
      max(task.Process) as Process, 
      max(task.Order) as Order, 
    FROM 
      dbo.TaskData AS task 
    GROUP BY 
      task.Code
  ) AS task 
  INNER JOIN dbo.QueryData AS query ON query.Code = task.CodeTask
```

В `dbo.TaskData` 8700 записей, после удаления дубликатов 6000 записей. В `dbo.QueryData` 8420 записей. В `dbo.QueryData` нет дубликатов. Получается, после объединения двух таблиц в одну, должно остаться 2420 не распределенных записей в `dbo.TaskData`. 
Вот так я пытаюсь их найти:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BrokenTask (Code, Power, Process, Order) 
SELECT 
  task.Code, 
  task.Power, 
  task.Process, 
  task.Order 
FROM 
  dbo.TaskData AS task 
  INNER JOIN dbo.DataFull AS fullData ON fullData.CodeTask = task.Code 
WHERE 
  not EXISTS (
    SELECT --это я понимаю как подзапрос
      CodeTask 
    from 
      dbo.DataFull -- 0 записей
    ---------------------------
    SELECT 
      Code
    FROM
      dbo.TaskData --0 записей
      )
```

Посмотрел в гайдах, что в подзапросе еще и `join`инят. Вряд ли же проблема из-за отсутствия джониа в подзапросе? Мне кажется, что `join` помог, если бы было больше записей чем ожидается, но у меня вообще 0 записей.

Comment: not exists сработает только в том случае если подзапрос ничего не нашел. Но запрос `SELECT 
      Code
    FROM
      dbo.TaskData` ничего не найдет только если таблица будет пустой ! Необходимо ограничить выборку, добавив в подзапрос условие where, которое ссылаясь на основную таблицу (из внешнего запроса) найдет или не найдет какие либо записи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался благодаря [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike). Вот так нужно:

```
SELECT 
  task.Code, 
  task.Power, 
  task.Process, 
  task.Order 
FROM 
  dbo.TaskData AS task 
WHERE 
  not EXISTS (
    SELECT 
      fullData.CodeTask 
    FROM 
      dbo.DataFull as fullData 
    WHERE 
      fullData.CodeTask = task.Code
  )
```